# How to put sessions on all pages without putting the session code on all views in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

I think my problem is related on the way I structured my pyramid project.
What I want to accomplish is to make my code runs on all views, I don't want to paste same codes on all views. Its like I will include the code in all views by just simply calling it. This is my code.

my wizard module

```
from pyramid.view import view_config, view_defaults
from .models import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyramid.response import Response
from bson import ObjectId
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound
import json

class WizardView:

def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request

@view_config(route_name='wizard', renderer='templates/wizard.jinja2')
def wizard(self):
    session = self.request.session
    if session:
        return {'fullname':session['name'],'userrole':session['userrole']}
    else:
        url = self.request.route_url('login')
        return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

my bill module

```
from pyramid.view import view_config, view_defaults
from .models import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyramid.response import Response
from bson import ObjectId 
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPFound

class BillView:

def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request

@view_config(route_name='bills', renderer='templates/bills.jinja2')
def bills(self):
    session = self.request.session
    if session:
        return {'fullname':session['name'],'userrole':session['userrole']}
    else:
        url = self.request.route_url('login')
        return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

As you can see I have to paste this code twice (this code checks if session exist, if not, then redirect user to login page)

```
session = self.request.session
if session:
    return {'fullname':session['name'],'userrole':session['userrole']}
else:
    url = self.request.route_url('login')
    return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

I've tried to search and I think what I need is some sort of auto loader? How can I apply this on pyramid? Or should I stick with this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to return exactly the same thing from both (many) views, then the best way is to use inheritance.

```
class GenericView:
    def __init__(self, request):
    self.request = request

    def generic_response(self):
        session = self.request.session
        if session:
            return {'fullname':session['name'],'userrole':session['userrole']}
        else:
            url = self.request.route_url('login')
            return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

Use `generic_response` in `WizardView` and `BillView`

```
class WizardView(GenericView):

    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)
        # Do wizard specific initialization

    @view_config(route_name='wizard', renderer='templates/wizard.jinja2')
    def wizard(self):
        return self.generic_response()

class BillView(GenericView):

    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)
        # Do bill specific initialization

    @view_config(route_name='bills', renderer='templates/bills.jinja2')
    def bills(self):
        return self.generic_response()
```

If you want to just check (and redirect) when session does not exists and otherwise proceed normally you could use custom exceptions and corresponding views.

First define custom exception

```
class SessionNotPresent(Exception):
    pass
```

And view for this exception

```
@view_config(context=SessionNotPresent)
def handle_no_session(context, request):
     # context is our custom exception, request is normal request
     request.route_url('login')
     return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

Then just check if session exists in parent constructor

```
class SessionView:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        if not self.request.session:
            raise SessionNotPresent() # Pyramid will delegate request handilng to handle_no_request
```

In views simply extend `SessionView` and non existing sessions will be handeled by `handle_no_session`.

```
class WizardView(SessionView):

    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)
        # Do wizard specific initialization

    @view_config(route_name='wizard', renderer='templates/wizard.jinja2')
    def wizard(self):
        session = self.request.session
        return {'fullname':session['name'],'userrole':session['userrole']}


class BillView(SessionView):

    def __init__(self, request):
        super().__init__(request)
        # Do bill specific initialization

    @view_config(route_name='bills', renderer='templates/bills.jinja2')
    def bills(self):
        session = self.request.session
        return {'fullname':session['name'],'userrole':session['userrole']}
```

You could easily add additional parameters to exception (`redirect_url`, ...)

For exception handling see http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use events: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/events.html

Example:

```
from pyramid.events import subscriber, NewRequest
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def check_session(event):
    if not event.request.session:
        raise HTTPFound(location=event.request.route_path('login'))
```